# ios memory leak in infinitely running application, particularly infinite video playback

Tags: ios, xcode, video, memory-leaks, infinite

I've been doing a project which theoretically should work indefinitely. This means that you started the program, connect Ipad to power supply and it works for days, months, years etc. I was faced with the fact that whatever I do, the memory is gradually allocated, but not released. Instruments Leaks show the absence of memory leaks, but in Instruments Allocations and Activity Monitor memory is gradually allocated, it grows and grows. There are a lot of places where it occurs, particularly when playing videos
A simple example (Xcode 4.3, no ARC):

**ViewController.h**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    MPMoviePlayerController *player;

}
```

**ViewController.m**

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:    [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mysite.com/movie.mp4"]];

    player.view.frame = CGRectMake(400, 500, 360, 240);
    [self.view addSubview:player.view];
    player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    player.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;  
    [player play];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
      [player stop];
      [player.view removeFromSuperview];
      [player release];
      [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (void)dealloc 
{
    [player release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

This simple application does nothing more, just loop video playback. Every 3 minutes is allocated an average of 100kb. Every day - an average of 40MB. I'm profiling with Instruments Activity Monitor. Over time, the app dies.
Whats wrong? Why memory is growing, when I just watch video(loop playback) and not initialize new objects?

Comment: Are you ever removing those subviews? Are you using ARC? If no, when do you `[player release]`? Make sure to resolve issues found by Build and Analyze, if any. Do [heap-shot analysis](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/).

Comment: Yes, I remove it in viewDidUnload. I do not use ARC. I'm release in viewDidUnload and dealloc. Analyze shows "No issues". I'm start the application, initialize and start player and nothing else was doing, just watch video, it looping play (MPMovieRepeatModeOne - play infinitely). I not turn off the application.

Answer (score 0):

The cache used for pre-loading input stream refreshes itself only if the app is loaded again or closed else it keeps accumulating data.Once you close the app and open again the memory assignment won'` be there.It's not a memory leak basically.

Also you need to remove MPMoviePlayerController notifications after it's use .
You will also have to release the players object .

And where are you using [player.view removeFromSuperview];

Comment: Yes, I do removeFromSuperview and release player, but memory is growing when I have just watching video.